# Powerdot - create both slides and notes via command line

Tags: presentations, notes, powerdot

I would like to create both slides and notes from a powerdot presentation easily.  Currently, the options in the preamble of the file need to be changed and the file saved to produce the different products.

Here is a sample of file which will produce the PDF of the slides via `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[
   nohandoutpagebreaks,
   mode=present,
   display=slides]{powerdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}[toc=]{Slide 1}
First Slide
\end{slide}

\begin{note}
First Note
\end{note}

\begin{slide}[toc=]{Slide 2}
Second slide
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

In order to produce the handouts I go into the file and change the document options, save the file, and recreate the PDF.

```
\documentclass[
   nohandoutpagebreaks,
   mode=handout,
   display=slidesnotes]{powerdot}
```

Finally to create a handout with just the notes the file is updated a last time, saved, and the PDF is recreated.

```
\documentclass[
   nohandoutpagebreaks,
   mode=handout,
   display=notes]{powerdot}
```

Is there are way that I can do this through the command-line, using a variable that is set in a shell script, or some other option?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro (e.g. `\display`) to hold the display option:

```
\documentclass[
   nohandoutpagebreaks,
   mode=present,
   display=\display]{powerdot}
```

Then you run `latex` in the following way:

```
$ latex "\def\display{slides}\input{<yourfilname-without-extension>}"
```

With this basic pattern it's simple to script both runs from the same document.

Comment: Thanks! This works well and I could add a second parameter   `latex "\def\display{slides}\def\mode{present}\input{<filename>}"`